# Filter Beautiful Soup 4 findings from parsed page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Evening,

I came to a dead-end while trying to figure how to solve this one.

In short I am parsing a product page with a  tag using BS4's findAll() function.I get the correct response but the area I am searching is "plain text" without tags that I can filter by using BS4 as far as I understand

```
def find_product(counter):
url = base_url
print('Looking in ' + url)
while not matches[counter]:
    print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    try:
        response1 = search_session.get(url)
    except:
        print('Unable to connect to site...')
        if counter == checkout_qty - 1:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            continue

    soup1 = bs(response1.text, 'html.parser')
    #soup1.find_all('script')
    soup2 = soup1.findAll('script', text = re.compile('id                : ')) #using text recompiling doesn't really do anything,just gives a slightly cleaner output of findings.
    print(soup2)
    for ids in soup2:
        link = ids.find(text = re.compile('id'))
        #i think i should use it somehow here,but I lack knowledge
        #this loop is unfinished


    break
```

This is what I am parsing from the product page.

```
<main class="B__container">
      <script>

  product.p = {
    id             : 47755536459,
    title          : "PRODUCT NAME",
    handle         : "PRODUCT HANDLE",
    vendor         : "",
    available      : ,
    images         : ["image-link.com\/files\/1111"],
    featured_image : "image-link.com\/files\/1111",
    options        : ["Size"],
    tags           : [],
    price          : 24000,
    variants       : []
  };

    product.p.variants.push({
      id                : 40113207495,
      parent_id         : 10025946759,
      available         : false,
      featured_image    : null,
      public_title      : null,
      requires_shipping : true,
      price             : 24000,
      options           : ["4"],
      option1           : "4",
      option2           : "",
      option3           : "",
      option4           : ""
    });

    product.p.variants.push({
      id                : 40113207559,
      parent_id         : 10025946759,
      available         : false,
      featured_image    : null,
      public_title      : null,
      requires_shipping : true,
      price             : 24000,
      options           : ["4.5"],
      option1           : "4.5",
      option2           : "",
      option3           : "",
      option4           : ""
    });

    product.p.variants.push({
      id                : 40113207623,
      parent_id         : 10025946759,
      available         : false,
      featured_image    : null,
      public_title      : null,
      requires_shipping : true,
      price             : 24000,
      options           : ["5"],
      option1           : "5",
      option2           : "",
      option3           : "",
      option4           : ""
    });
  </script>
```

My goal is to extract the id with the number and then later send it off to a separate function.

The problem,lack of knowledge or I lack skills of how to use BS4 to its full potential to get out what I want.

Comment: Can you post the url ? You have two possible solutions: 1) try to get the info directly from the website or 2) proccess this block of text to get what you want...

Comment: These arrays of 'variants' are the most direct way of getting the necessary items for the task. I need to gather the 'id',specifically the numbers 'id' is being assigned with and use it to add the item to cart. Could you give me guidelines on how I cold process these arrays/block of text to filter out the necessary data?

Comment: The block of text that come after "This is what I am parsing from the product page." is `soup2` ?

Comment: Yes. Everything in between <script> and </script> is the output i get from soup2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code... it's just string manipulation to fetch the necessary info.. in this case, `id` value.

1. split data at `\n`
2. `for` each element in this list, check if substring `id` is present
3. if `True`, print the row after a few manipulations (`strip`, `split`, `replace`)

**Code:**

```
s = soup2.text
data = s.split('\n')

for i, d in enumerate(data):
    if " id " in d:
        print(data[i].strip().split(':')[1].replace(',', ''))
```

**Output:**

```
47755536459
40113207495
40113207559
40113207623
```

**Edited Code:**

```
for ids in soup2:
    s = ids.text
    data = s.split('\n')

    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        if " id " in d:
            print(data[i].strip().split(':')[1].replace(',', ''))
```

Instead of `print`, you can `append` each id to a `list` and use them later.

Comment: For some reason I am getting an error related to 's': "s = soup2.text
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'" This is how I implemented your code: `soup1 = bs(response1.text, 'html.parser')
        #soup1.find_all('script')
        soup2 = soup1.findAll('script')
        print(soup2) #testing purposes
        s = soup2.text
        data = s.split('\n')

        for i, d in enumerate(data):
            if " id " in d:
                print(data[i].strip().split(':')[1].replace(',', ''))` P.S Pardon me for not knowing how to format the comments correctly

Comment: The `find_all` method returns a `ResultSet` object, which you can iterate over using a `for` loop. So, you should either use a `for` loop to loop through each found `script` and then use `.text` to convert it, or use `find` instead of `find_all` to get only the 1st script element. Btw, I think it'll work if you use `for ids in soup2: s = ids.text ` and so on...